# Why is only one table created?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbset

I use one model for several tables, but when I create the tables, only one of them is created. Why is that and can it be changed?

```
  public DbSet<ShopItemProperty_Model> Champagne_TBL { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShopItemProperty_Model> Gin_TBL { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShopItemProperty_Model> Rum_TBL { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShopItemProperty_Model> SparklyWine_TBL { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShopItemProperty_Model> Whisky_TBL { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShopItemProperty_Model> WhiteWine_TBL { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShopItemProperty_Model> RedWine_TBL { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShopItemProperty_Model> Wodka_TBL { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EfCore Create table based on your types, so
If you have to do this you can take one model as a abstract class and define another models which inherited from that.

Also i have to say this database design it could be better , i don't know your business but easiest way is create a table with special descriminator like enum

```
public abstract class ShopItemProperty_Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    /* Other fields */
}

[Table("Gin_TBL")]
public class Gin_TBL : ShopItemProperty_Model
{
}

[Table("Rum_TBL")]
public class Rum_TBL : ShopItemProperty_Model
{
}

[Table("SparklyWine_TBL")]
public class SparklyWine_TBL : ShopItemProperty_Model
{
}

[Table("Whisky_TBL")]
public class Whisky_TBL : ShopItemProperty_Model
{
}

[Table("WhiteWine_TBL")]
public class WhiteWine_TBL : ShopItemProperty_Model
{
}

[Table("RedWine_TBL")]
public class RedWine_TBL : ShopItemProperty_Model
{
}

[Table("Wodka_TBL")]
public class Wodka_TBL : ShopItemProperty_Model
{
}
```